# iOS app not displaying correctly on device

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I have a relatively simple app that runs perfectly on the simulator, but when I try and run the exact same application on an actual device I get something different, my container view shows up as completely black and elements within the content view don't show up.

Here are some images:

Xcode:
[image]

Simulator:
[image]

Actual device (iPhone):
[image]

Comment: If the background color on the container view is set to default, and the device is in dark mode, that would explain why it is showing up as black. Setting it explicitly to white would fix that problem.

Comment: I tried setting it up explicitly and it still shows black. But even if the UIView is black, shouldn’t the images show?

Comment: experiment with different colours for various elements, backgrounds, buttons and see what show up where. it's difficult to tell what's happening without having access to your code and storyboard. don't be afraid to move things around, adding new UI elements to the mix, etc.

Comment: It also looks like the buttons might not actually be within the container view, but are instead on top of it. I'm not sure if that was intentional or not, but I second what EarlGrey said, it's hard to tell what's going on without the storyboard itself.

Comment: Ok, thanks, it turns out the problem was that I had alpha of that UIView to 1 and so changing that value fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that I had alpha of that UIView to 1 and so changing that value fixed it